# Check for the migration in ASP.NET MVC framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, migration, database-migration, entity-framework-migrations

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SMupg.png)

> An error occurred while accessing the Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting services. Continuing without the application service provider.
>
> Error: Failed to load configuration from file 'C:\Users\Lenovo\OneDrive\Desktop\Project H\Demo\StudentData\appsettings.json'.
> Unable to create an object of type 'StudentDbContext'. For the different patterns supported at design time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728

I have tried viewing things in `appsettings.json` also and a lot of other stuff from Youtube too still no issue like this before

Comment: please explain what you tried and not working